# How to connect to putty via Selenium-Java to execute set of commands and validate the output in putty window

Tags: java, selenium, jscript

How to connect to putty via Selenium-Java to execute set of commands and validate the output in putty window?
seeing various options and posts for trying out plink.exe and downloading autoit

Comment: And what kind of problem you encountered when you tried those options?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is for automating test cases using browser. Hence, it can work only on browsers, not on operating systems.

If you want to play with *nix operating systems by remotely logging into them with putty and run *nix commands using java code, I would recommend using below open source libraries.

1. [sshj](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj)
2. [jcraft](http://www.jcraft.com/)

If you wish to use [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) for running *nix commands, you can take advantage of Java [RunTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751944/how-to-execute-unix-commands-through-windows-cygwin-using-java)

Hope this helps! Good luck.